# npm permission issue on fresh install of Homestead / Vagrant / Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant

Two days dealing with this issue and it is winning.

I have a fresh install of `Windows 10` host, running the latest versions of `Vagrant`, `laravel/homestead (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS box, v 6.0.0)`, `Virtualbox`, `laravel`, `git for windows`, `node.js for windows`.

`vagrant`, `git`, `virtualbox` are set to run as administrator in `windows`.

I create a `Laravel` project called blog like this:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

All creates OK. I then try and install `npm` like this:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src/blog$ npm install -g npm@latest
```

And I get:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules/npm\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-05-05T00_57_41_110Z-debug.log
```

But when i check `vagrant` user permissions:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src/blog$ groups
vagrant adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

So I solve this with the not recommended by `npm` message:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src/blog$ sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

I now go and install an `npm` package like `highcharts`:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src/blog$ npm install --save highcharts
npm WARN rollback Rolling back highcharts@6.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.2262439515'
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.2262439515
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.2262439515' -> '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-05-05T01_10_24_241Z-debug.log
```

I try sudo to install package, same result

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src/blog$ sudo npm install --save --no-bin-links highcharts 
npm WARN rollback Rolling back highcharts@6.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.1984492036'
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.1984492036
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json.1984492036' -> '/home/vagrant/src/blog/node_modules/highcharts/package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-05-05T01_58_13_140Z-debug.log
```

The result is a `highchatrts` folder in `node_modules` with only the `packaje.json.1984492036` file in it.

I cannot seem to find a way around this. Using `--no-bin-links` gives the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Mohdule exactly same result. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122289/470749 says *not* to run `sudo` and links to the official documentation describing how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got it all working by running `npm install` from the `git` host os, not from the `ubuntu` vm. Not what I wanted but I move forward and have learned something and creeped closer to insanity...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue two days ago, try running `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm` , undo any changes you made first though, cause i don't know how valet works (sad Linux user)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm highcharts` and same result, exactly the same.

Comment: np, you are welcome, sorry i was not clear, i meant running the command with --unsafe-perm to install npm itself, but apparently you've solved that issue already
  
hmmmm..
have you tried doing what the message says (renaming the package.json), better yet removing the whole node_modules folder

Comment: I have. The puzzling thing is this is all FRESH. so when I do `npm install` per `Laravel` installation instructions the folder structure is created and for each packages, I get empty folders with the `package.json.123124321` file in each. npm runs by `vagrant` user and it seems it has no rights to rename this file. Yet it can create folders. `composer` is also used by `vagrant` and it has no problems creating project. #beaten