# npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc Not working?

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

`npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc` not working it is showing error

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc' npm ERR!     at Error
>   (native) npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc'] npm ERR!   errno:
>   -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc' } npm ERR!  npm
>   ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log

Comment: npm install -g needs sudo

Comment: Throwing an error

Comment: @ChaitanyaRajeev I think what @raven means is that in order for `npm install -g` to affect the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` directory, it needs to be running as a user that has write access to that folder.  Prefixing the command with `sudo` will ensure this happens.

Comment: npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/chaitanya
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo npm install  -g ethereumjs-testrpc`
You have to run this command as superuser otherwise it won't run . because it's trying to accessed your filesystem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058546/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-lib-node-modules/49122289#49122289

Comment: It's not recommended to use sudo with npm install :)

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack Hey! But what if we do use sudo , how will it create permission issue messed up ? I don't understand this.