# React Native Installation Error on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, web-deployment-project

Whenever I type and try to install React Native on my Ubuntu Machine then I use this code:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Then I execute the code and i get this error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to 
/usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
'/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
'/usr/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
'/usr/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this 
file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please 
double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or 
try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not 
recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/atharva/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_37_39_233Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo npm install -g expo-cli`.

The problems related in permission could be solved with a `root` permission.

But It is recommended way from npmjs official docs.

> Another question same as you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122289/515932
>
> Official: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: No getting the same!

Comment: @AtharvaSawant Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if u have used:

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
```

command and still you are getting same issue, 
first please check that npm, expo and react-native are properly installed or not.

```
npm -v
expo --version
react-native --version
```

follow one of these instructions:

1. go to root, and enter the below command:

   **sudo su**

   **npm install -g expo-cli**
2. as normal user use this command to install expo-cli:

   **sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm expo-cli**

Hope this helps and resolve your issue.